# Android Widget - works first time only

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a widget, that on click of a text view, launches a new activity which is an editText to allow the user to search. After you search, it opens the app at the desired results. If the user puts the app in the background, and does not press back, when the user goes to click on the widget again, instead of bring up the search editText view, it opens the app to where it left off.

Ideally I want to bring up the search box everytime, even if it overlays the app behind it. Any thoughts? Code is below:

SearchWidgetClass:

```
public class SearchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String SHOW_POPUP_DIALOG_ACTION = "launch.search.widget";
    private static final String LAUNCH_WIDGET = "launch.homescreen.widget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SearchWidget.class);

        int[] allWidgetInstancesIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        for (int widgetId : allWidgetInstancesIds) {

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.search_widget_layout);

            // Create an intent that when received will launch the search bar
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(context, SearchWidget.class);
            searchIntent.setAction(SHOW_POPUP_DIALOG_ACTION);

            // Create an intent that when received will open the app on the home screen
            Intent WidgetIntent = new Intent(context, SearchWidget.class);
            WidgetIntent.setAction(LAUNCH_WIDGET);

            PendingIntent searchPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, searchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            PendingIntent openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, WidgetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Set up the onClickListener of the widget
            // Now, when the widget is pressed the pendingIntent will be sent
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_search_textview, searchPendingIntent);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_open, openPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

        }//End of For Each loop

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }//End of onUpdate method

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent actionIntent;

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SHOW_POPUP_DIALOG_ACTION)) {

            actionIntent = new Intent(context, SearchWidgetDialogActivity.class);
            actionIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(actionIntent);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(LAUNCH_WIDGET)){
            actionIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            actionIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(actionIntent);
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);

    }//End of onReceive method

}//End of SearchWidget Class
```

Search Dialog Activity:

```
public class SearchWidgetDialogActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText searchWidgetEditText;
    private String actionArg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.search_widget_dialog_layout);

        LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        searchWidgetEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_widget_edit_text);

        searchWidgetEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if (((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) &&
                        (!StringUtils.isEmpty(searchWidgetEditText.getText().toString()))) {

                    handleWidgetAction(SearchWidgetDialogActivity.this);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }//End of onCreate method

    public void handleWidgetAction(Context aContext) {

            actionArg = searchWidgetEditText.getText().toString();
            QLog.d("Launching search activity for " + actionArg + " from the widget");
            Intent serachProductsIntent = new Intent(aContext, BrowseProductsSearchActivity.class);
            serachProductsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            serachProductsIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
            serachProductsIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, actionArg);
            serachProductsIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.USER_QUERY, actionArg);
            aContext.startActivity(serachProductsIntent);

    }//End of handleWidgetSearch method

}// End of SearchWidgetDialogActivity class
```

Manifest Activities:

```
<activity
            android:name="android.activities.SearchWidgetDialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>


<receiver 
            android:name="android.widget.SearchWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="launch.search.widget"/>
                <action android:name="launch.homescreen.widget"/>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/search_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
```

Comment: what's the error? show logcat

Comment: There is not an error, just on second time the user clicks on the widget when the app is in the background, it just launches the app from where it left off instead of launching the search widget.

I have a feeling its something to do with the onResume/onStop